Angular Tour of Heroes HttpErrorResponse SyntaxError
Following step 6. of the tutorial, I'm using HttpClient to get data from the in-memory Web API. The build completes but I get my index.html file which results in a HttpErrorResponse with
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON...
text: "<!doctype html> <html lang="en-us"> <head>...
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/anime-list"
Using Angular v17
I've tried:

changing responseType from text to json
adding, removing 'api' from the url
adding, removing 'api' from the route paths
rearranging route precedence
downgrading in-memory-web-api from 0.18.0 to lower versions
using app.module.ts and app-routing.module.ts instead of app.route.ts and app.config.ts

Could this just be an issue between v16 and v17? Has anyone else run into this issue? Thank you and feel free to leave any tips on how to better format questions.
Note: arbitrarily replaced heroes with anime for personal preference
anime.service.ts:
animeListUrl = 'api/anime-list';

getAnimeList(): Observable<Anime[]> {
    return this.http.get<Anime[]>(this.animeListUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched animeList')), 
      catchError(this.handleError<Anime[]>('getAnimeList', [])));
  }

app.routes.ts:
export const routes: Routes = [
    //{path: 'api/anime-list', component: AnimeComponent}
    {path: 'anime-list', component: AnimeComponent},
    {path: 'top-anime', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'detail/:id', component: AnimeDetailComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/anime-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
    //{path: '', redirectTo: '/api/anime-list', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { LoggingInterceptor } from './logging-interceptor';
import { IronHttpInterceptor } from './iron/iron-http-interceptor';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AnimeDetailComponent } from './anime-detail/anime-detail.component';
import { AnimeComponent } from './anime/anime.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns simulated server responses.
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    )
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    AnimeComponent,
    AnimeDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoggingInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: IronHttpInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }


seems like nothings intercepting the http.get... check your app.module.ts file against the stackblitz version: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts  (particularly the HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule bit...)

Thank you for the response browsermator! After comparing, I added logging and iron interceptors which were missing from my app.module.ts, but I'm still getting the error unfortunately. I've edited my post to show this change :)

that link doesn't seem to work anymore, but I don't remember seeing anything in the tutorial or the sample that referenced IronHttpInterceptor or LoggingInterceptor.

I would just skip over that bit of the tutorial and use a real backend for your requests.  It's no use learning/troubleshooting this as it's only useful for tutorial purposes.

Hello again! After finding the link didn't work, I googled stackblitz to find the page where I saw the interceptors. Although it didn't work, I learned something new. But yes, I think I'll take your suggestion to use a real backend or move on to expand other parts of my website, for now. Thank you!
